# Why there are some "meaningless" memory slot in the disassembly code?

Tags: linux, memory-management, assembly, disassembly, memory-alignment

I use objdump to disassemble some ELF file on 32 bit Linux.

The asm file are in Intel format.

In the disassemble file, I notice some memory slot like below:

```
80483ed:       c7 44 24 18 07 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x18],0x7
80483f4:       00
80483f5:       c7 44 24 1c 0c 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0xc
80483fc:       00
80483fd:       c7 44 24 20 01 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x20],0x1
8048404:       00
8048405:       c7 44 24 24 fe ff ff    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x24],0xfffffffe
804840c:       ff
```

and the original assemble file is :

```
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+24], 7
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+28], 12
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+32], 1
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+36], -2
```

Could anyone tell me what does the memory address like "80483f4","80483fc" do?

Is this issue related to the **memory alignment**?

Thank you!

Comment: Add `-w` to your `objdump` command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are part of the previous line's operands.  The "immediate" (constant) numbers are encoded as 32-bits.  So 0x07 takes up 4 bytes: `07 00 00 00`.  Whatever you're using to disable is showing you the last byte on a different line.